# Outlook Add-in links broken in desktop app

Tags: reactjs, outlook, office-js, office-addins

Currently I have an outlook add-in that works great on the web version of Outlook and desktop version of Outlook on the mac. The add-in also works fine on multiple web browsers with outlook online (IE11 included). However, for certain windows users, the desktop Outlook add-in fails to work correctly. In particular, links do not work in the desktop version. Per the docs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/concepts/browsers-used-by-office-web-add-ins if my add-in works in IE 11 web browser, it should work in the desktop app.

Can anyone provide links to help me troubleshoot the add-in on the desktop version of windows? I am at a complete loss as to why it would work in IE11 but not on the desktop version of outlook.

This add in was started with the yeoman generator if that helps.

Comment: For those certain users, does the add-in work in Edge on their machines? For debugging add-in with Windows Outlook Desktop, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/debug-add-ins-using-f12-developer-tools-on-windows-10

Comment: The add-in works on edge and IE 11 so there is nothing to debug in the browser.

Comment: Look at the part 'When the add-in is running in Internet Explorer' in the docs linked above. You have to use the F12 dev tools (found in windows folder) to debug the webview that runs the addin inside the Outlook Desktop client.

Comment: When you say links do not work, I believe you are saying that nothing happens when a user clicks on them. If that is accurate, do you see any error in the debug console using the F12 developer tools? Can you share such error?

Comment: did you check the IE protected mode for those users.?

Comment: Thanks for the help, I ended up playing with a bunch of poly fill settings and removing components until it rendered. not ideal but there was nothing useful in any debug logs.